# Configure success/failed notifications with github webhooks

Tags: github, workflow, github-pages, github-actions

I just want to try to send notification to a discord server with github webhook.

For that, I've created a token with discord add I've added it into the webhooks settings. Now, if I do some changes on my github pages, I receive some notifications in my discord channel :

[image]

I deploy my blog with github pages and a workflows and I would like to have only the notifications of the workflows. To do that, I've changed some parameters :

In the **Let me select individual events**, just keep :

- Workflow runs
- Workflow jobs
- Page builds

But now, I received no notifications on my channel...

Someone to tell me how to configure my worflows in order to have the notifications of the success or the failed of the deployment of my blog ? Maybe keep an other option ? Add an option on my github deploy-site.yaml file ?

Thanks !